# @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT) with @ManyToOne

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to use `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)` with `ManyToOne` relationship but its throwing error, why `subselect` doesn't works with `ManyToOne`?

Answer (score 1):

subselect fetching is only available for collections and not for entity ... that is to say any `ToMany` associations ... and it is really powerful to get collection of collection, like, for ex, getting a list of Person and fetch the adresses of each Person at the same time ... (provided that one Person may have many adresses of course)

There are other fetching options (such as `FetchMode.JOIN`) for `ToOne`associations you may want to have a look at ...

Comment: The question was more of a *why*.

Comment: Agree, it's a valid usecase. I have one example where a join doesn't use the correct indices, while a subselect gets it right. An alternative is ofc JOOQ.